# Inconsequent text citations

Tags: biblatex, author-number

I want maximum one citation name in my text. Therefore I used the option `maxcitenames=1` in the biblatex package. This works for all my references except for two: `verdonck2009` and `verdonck2011`. I am not sure whether this is because the author name is the same or because of some other reason. I have put a MWE example below together with my bibtex references. The result of the MWE example is added in the image at the bottom. As you can see it uses only one citation name, except for `verdonck2009` and `verdonck2011`. Any ideas on how this can be solved?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[backend=biber, natbib=true, style=authoryear, maxcitenames=1, maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib/literature.bib}

\begin{document}

In \citet{verdonck2009}, \citet{verdonck2011}, \citet{kaas2008} and \citet{england2002} is stated that...

\printbibliography
\end{document}

@article{verdonck2009,
title={A robustification of the chain-ladder method},
author={Verdonck, T and Van Wouwe, M and Dhaene, J},
journal={North American Actuarial Journal},
volume={13},
number={2},
pages={280--298},
year={2009},
publisher={Taylor \& Francis}
}

@article{england2002,
title={Stochastic claims reserving in general insurance},
author={England, P  and Verrall, R},
journal={British Actuarial Journal},
volume={8},
number={03},
pages={443--518},
year={2002},
publisher={Cambridge Univ Press}
}

@article{verdonck2011,
title={The influence of individual claims on the chain-ladder estimates: Analysis and diagnostic tool},
author={Verdonck, T and Debruyne, M},
journal={Insurance: Mathematics and Economics},
volume={48},
number={1},
pages={85--98},
year={2011},
publisher={Elsevier}
}

@book{kaas2008,
title={Modern actuarial risk theory: using R},
author={Kaas, R and Goovaerts, M and Dhaene, J and Denuit, M},
volume={128},
year={2008},
publisher={Springer Science \& Business Media}
}
```

[image]

Comment: I added the 'uniquelist=false' option, as proposed in the questioned you referred to, but this does not seem to change anything.

Comment: I seem to remember you asked a very similar question a few weeks ago, but cannot find it now. If `uniquelist=false` does not help you need to give us more information. What version of `biblatex`/Biber do you use. Try making an update of your distribution, to make sure they are up-to-date.

Comment: @PieterKJ Did you remove the auxiliary files and rerun LaTeX/Biber/LaTeX?

Comment: @PieterKJ I tested it, and it works for me.

Comment: You are right. I forgot to run LaTeX before running biber. Stupid. Many thanks!

Comment: Since the problem seems to be solved by running Biber again (as confirmed by the OP above), I'm voting to close as proposed by lockstep.